# How to update a global variable from within a function in Python 3?

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I'm trying to run an optimization step and I want to update a global variable from within a function.  I'm using an optimization script and I want to save the data when there are any updates but I cannot update the global variable from within a function.

**Is there a way to update a global variable from within a function call?**  I am making sure not to run the optimization step in parallel so this technically should be ok.

```
global current_minimum
current_minimum = 0

def update():
    current_minimum = -0.1

_ = update()
print(current_minimum)
# 0
```

Comment: `global` goes inside the function, not at top level. (`global` at top level really ought to be a syntax error.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `global current_minimum` **within** the function where you are updating said variable. Otherwise the function thinks `current_minimum` is a local variable.